# How to call a C program in shell script?

Tags: shell

I have a simple question. I want to execute a C program in a shell script. How do I do that? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It should be possible just by putting the program's name on the line. What have you tried and what happened?

Comment: This question is either too simple or too complex. Please provide an example of what you want to do. All of what goes on in  a shell script involves calling C programs.

Comment: Not executing any C program in a shell script would be more challenging ...

Comment: It's worth noting that you execute a C program in a shell script in *exactly the same way* as you would if you were executing it yourself in the shell, in the same context that that line of the shell script would be in (same directory, same environment, etc.).

Comment: @Chris Lutz: I didn't wrote impossible and anyway, exit, being part of the shell itself, is likely to be written in C.

Comment: @jlliagre - `exit` is likely to be a builtin, so the script is not executing any C programs, but simply running code within the (currently executing) shell program. You're not running any new programs, which _is_ most of what one does in a shell. Anyway, it's a silly semantic difference. We've turned a joke into an argument.

Comment: "exit" can hardly not be a builtin. Shell builtins are eventually written in C but the initial question doesn't make much sense. You don't call a C program in the first place as there is no (mainstream) C interpreter available. You call internal commands, scripts, binaries and similar beasts, but not C programs. C programs are designed to be compiled, not called.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, ...all of what goes on in a *badly written* script, anyhow. Bash has a rich set of string manipulation primitives, ample I/O capabilities, and data types that, while primitive, are better than the "can't do anything but store strings" capabilities widely assumed/leveraged; unnecessary use of external programs in common practice is part of how it got an even-worse-than-deserved reputation for inefficiency.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming this is linux/unix we're talking about:

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/executable arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 6):

```
cc hello_world.c #produces a.out
./a.out #run your program
```

IMHO, your problem is the $PATH. Your current directory is not in PATH, so when you enter

```
a.out
```

your shell respond:

```
-bash: a.out: command not found
```

you **should** execute it as

```
./a.out
```

(or add "." to your PATH, but this is *not* recommended.)

Answer (score 3):

Almost every program that you execute in a shell script is a C program (but some, often many, of the commands you execute may be built into the shell).  You execute a C program in the same way as any other program:

- By basename: `command [arg1 ...]`

  - The command must be in a directory searched by the shell - on your PATH, in other words.
- By relative name: `./command [arg1 ...]` or `../../bin/command [arg1 ...]`

  - The program must exist and be executable (by you)
- By absolute name: `/some/directory/bin/command [arg1 ...]`

  - The program must exist and be executable (by you)

One of the beauties of Unix is that programs you create, whether in C or any other language, attain the same status as the system-provided commands.  The only difference is that the system-provided commands are in a different place (such as `/bin` or `/usr/bin`) from commands you create (such as `usr/local/bin` or `$HOME/bin`).