# How to call a c++ program in a shell script

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell, sh

How to call a c++ program in a shell script, is it the same as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969978/how-to-call-a-c-program-in-shell-script)?

When I run a shell script I should get result of a c++ program.

Comment: Did you try calling it like a C program? If yes, what went wrong?

Comment: The answer is the exact same as the question you linked.

Comment: The answer to that question is the same as the answer to yours.

Answer (score 3):

You, ah, run *any* program from a shell script by, um, *calling* it.  All you need is a path to the executable and use that as your first string in the shell line.  And command line agruments go after that (on the same line).

Comment: This answer is 100% correct and reasonably friendly given circumstances. I'm upvoting.